# Conditionally Ignore reference mapping

Tags: csvhelper

Is it possible to programatically/dynamically ignore a reference mapping if it satisfies a certain condition?

Consider the following structure

```cs
public class SkuDto
{
    public string Name;
    public InnerSkuDto InnerSku;
}

public class InnerSkuDto
{
    public Guid SkuNumber;
}

public sealed class SkuMap : ClassMap<SkuDto>
{
    Map(m => m.Name);
    References<InnerSkuMap>(m => m.InnerSku);
}

public sealed class InnerSkuMap : ClassMap<InnerSkuDto> { ... }
```

Now sometimes the `InnerSku` property in the `SkuDto` object can be null in which case the resulting CSV output contains 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 for the `SkuNumber` instead of an empty cell. So is it possible to ignore the `InnerSku` if its null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Guid` can't be null, so it defaults to an empty `Guid`, which you see in the CSV output.  One solution is to change `SkuNumber` to a nullable `Guid`

```cs
public class InnerSkuDto
{
    public Guid? SkuNumber;
}
```

If you can't or don't want to change `SkuNumber` to a nullable `Guid`, the other option is to use a custom converter.  Here I override the `ConvertToString` method of `GuidConverter`.

```cs
public class EmptyGuidConverter : GuidConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if ((Guid)value == Guid.Empty)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return base.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData);
    }
}

public sealed class InnerSkuMap : ClassMap<InnerSkuDto>
{
    public InnerSkuMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SkuNumber).TypeConverter<EmptyGuidConverter>();
    }
}
```

Or instead of registering the converter for a single property, you can register it with your `CsvWriter` for all `Guid` values. Just make sure to add it before registering your `ClassMap`.

```cs
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<Guid>(new EmptyGuidConverter());
```

Comment: Yes I figured that would be the only way to about this however I wasnt aware we could globally register a type converter so thanks for that!